# Mistakenly moved the server files to a directory and the server wont work now

Tags: mv, amazon-linux

I screwed up my AWS instance.

I created a new directory `demo` inside my `/var/www/html`

Then in navigated to the `html` directory and ran this command:

`sudo mv /* demo`

And all the files and folders from the server root appeared in the `demo` directory.

How do I move it back?

Also, my intention was to move all the files/folders inside the `html` directory to the `demo` folder.

Comment: Please comment why vote down :)

Answer (score 1):

I saw this happen two or three years ago, and I'm aware there are different AWS setups, so this might be doable or might not be.

The machine could no longer be reached through SSH (it did allow login, but the shell would not start). There was no "hardware" terminal available as there is on other services.

If your machine can fire up a root shell, then the commands

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/www/html/demo/lib /var/www/html/demo/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /var/www/html/demo/bin/mv /var/www/html/demo/usr /
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/www/html/demo/lib /var/www/html/demo/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /var/www/html/demo/bin/mv /var/www/html/demo/var /
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/var/www/html/demo/lib /var/www/html/demo/lib/ld-linux.so.2 /var/www/html/demo/bin/mv /var/www/html/demo/lib /
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /var/www/html/demo/bin/mv /var/www/html/demo/bin /
```

should bring you to a sufficiently recoverable state.

If there is a terminal allowing login through VNC, Remote Desktop or whatever, same thing.

In our case neither worked.

What the then-administrator did was fire up another temporary AWS instance, force dirty shutdown of the damaged instance, detach its disk, and attach it to the new instance as secondary disk.

Then he did the equivalent of

```
mount /mnt /dev/sdb1
cd /mnt/var/www/html/demo
mv * /mnt/
sync
shutdown -h now
```

and detached the disk, reattaching to the old instance, which apart from a lenghty fsck due to the dirty shutdown booted with no problems.